# Browser updates against w3c spec's

Tags: browser, w3c, specifications

I closely monitor w3c specs such as http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/ and am implementing aspects of them as soon as functionality hits a majority of browsers, however I am looking for a resource that can tell me at what stage of implementation each browser is at.

I can review sites such as http://findmebyip.com/litmus, but this is now a little out of date as it does not dynamically update from the browser builds (which are very frequent right now).

does a resource like this exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/). The site has very comprehensive tables of support status for various features across different browsers, and is kept up to date. There's also [an update feed](http://feeds.feedburner.com/WhenCanIUse) which can be worth following.